# iPhone : MPMoviePlayerController Dismiss itself before playing video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play video(.mp4) in my app using following code.

```
   NSString *doc = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

   NSString *moviePath = [doc stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mp4"];
   NSLog(@"Movie Path : %@",moviePath);
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:moviePath];
   NSLog(@"URL : %@",url);

   MPMoviePlayerViewController* controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

   [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];
   //[controller release];
```

It shows view for playing video but within a second it use to dismiss the MPMoviePlayerController view and comes back into my view.

What could be wrong ?

Comment: check your movie file playable duration it could be of 1 second!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace below line in your code

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
```